# Splitting Large XML file into multiple files

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, lxml

I tried to split a large XML file (65GB) using the following code but it takes a long time (I think because of string concatenation) 
the XML format is like

```
<posts>
<row id= ....   />
<row id= ....   />
<row id= ....   />
<row id= ....   />
.
.
.
</posts>
```

```
from lxml import etree

context = etree.iterparse('Posts.xml', tag='row', events=('end', ))
index = 0
count = 0
full_text = b""
for event, elem in context:
    count += 1
    full_text += etree.tostring(elem)
    if count >= 1000000 :
        count = 0
        index += 1
        filename = format(str(index) + ".xml")
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(b"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n")
            f.write(b"<root>\n")
            f.write(full_text)
            f.write(b"</root>")
            full_text = b""
with open(format(str(index+1)+".xml"), 'wb') as f:
    f.write(b"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n")
    f.write(b"<root>\n")
    f.write(full_text)
    f.write(b"</root>")
```

I want to split it into like 1GB files for further processing

Is there any efficient way to justify the following code ?

P.S. [Same topics didn't help]

Answer (score 0):

I can't get you all the way there, but below is how I would approach it.

I would start with:

```
from lxml import html
import lxml.etree as le

tree = html.fromstring(content) #content would be your whole file
```

I would then count the number of nodes in your `tree`, this way:

```
num_nodes = tree.xpath("count(//book)") #'book' in your case would be whatever the critical item is
```

Once you have that number, I would decide into how many files I would divide those nodes. Say you have 12 nodes and decided to devide them into 3 files, nodes 1-4 would be in `file 1`, 5-8 in `file 2`, etc. Let's focus on `file 2`:

From your `tree` you need to select the nodes in the positions assigned to `file 2`. So, for this file:

```
low_pos=5
hi_pos=8
items = tree.xpath('//book[position()>=low_pos and position()<=hi_pos]')
```

This should select the relevant nodes and all their tags, text, etc.

Finally, you take each of the items, and do with it what you will:

```
for item in items:
    print(le.tostring(item).decode('utf-8'))#or write or whatever
```

It obviously is going to take a lot of work to implement it in your case, but hopefully it's at least a start...

Comment: _#content would be your whole file_ - The entire 65GB file? Ouch. Also, why use html if the input files are XML?

Comment: @DanielHaley - than maybe he should just split manually first into somewhat smaller chunks... Anyway, that's the best I could do - just trying to help him out.